# Run Python Procedure From Another Python File

Tags: python, import, bluetooth

I am having problem's calling one python procedure from another. This solution would likely not justify an "import".

The problem is that one Python script has an active Bluetooth connection to a device. I need information from a second Python script to be sent through the Bluetooth port of the first python script.

Essentially, the first python file (file1.py) has this sub:

```
 def output(string):

       bluetoothsock.send(string)
```

And the second file should be able to do something like this:

```
file1.output("randomtext")
```

And the first python file should send the "randomtext" string. Any ideas would be helpful!

File1.py example:

```
from bluetooth import *
try:
   sock.connect((target_address, port))
   sock.settimeout(timeout)
except:
   print("Timeout",3)


def output(text):
   try:
      sock.send(str(text))
      return ("Sent Successfully!",True)
   except:
      return("Error Sending",False)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `import`? Of course, a Python file does need to be structured properly if you want to import it, but that shouldn't be a big deal if you write clean code.

Comment: I have used import and it did not send anything. I assume that by importing, it simply adds the procedure from on file into another, which would not give access to the Bluetooth port. I know that the Bluetooth segment works as sending information within "file1.py" works.

Comment: Ok. It looks like you are using a global variable `bluetoothsock` in `file1.py`. So to use it from another file you may need to modify `file1.py` slightly. It will be a lot easier to give recommendations if you paste `file1.py` into your question so that we don't have to guess what's going on. If it contains a lot of other stuff apart from functions & classes directly dealing with opening & using the Bluetooth socket, it would be good idea to just post a modified version of `file1.py` that only contains the Bluetooth stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the relevant code.

Comment: Whoops, I fixed the mistake.  I had tried to import file1 and used file1.output("randomstring"), except it had never sent anything through the bluetooth port. Thanks for your persistance!

Answer (score 0):

In file2.py, do

```
import file1
file1.output("randomtext")
```

The interpreter will execute the code in the `try:.. except:` block in `file1.py` during the importation process, so the socket will be open & you *should* then be able to send data using `file1.output()`.

If that deosn't work please paste the output, including any error message into your question.

FWIW, the code in `file1.py` uses some questionable techniques, eg `from bluetooth import *` and `try:.. except:` without a named exception. It might be a good idea to tell us what package that bluetooth module comes from.